# Functional component - calling useEffect on state change, but not when props changed

Tags: reactjs

Working with a functional component which has the following two useEffects:

```
  //update the state when props changed
  useEffect(() => {
    const newState = mapPropsToState(props);
    if (!_.isEqual(newState, state)) {
      setState(newState);
    }
  }, [props]);

  //make an API call
  useEffect(() => {
    preferencesChanged();
  }, [state]);
```

State is derived from props, so the purpose of the first useEffect is to respond to a change in props and update the state.

The purpose of the second useEffect is to make an API call when state has changed. However, this API call can result in the props of this component changing (since `preferencesChanged()` updates the state of a parent component).

What I really want is for the setState in the first useEffect to be done "quietly" and not to trigger the 2nd useEffect.

Is this possible? Or am I thinking about this design in completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

1. State is derived from props.
   You can just do your logic inside of component (in render phase), instead of calling it in an effect:

```
//...
const newState = mapPropsToState(props);
// ...
```

and you can use `useMemo` if that is an expensive calculation:

```
const newState = useMemo(() => mapPropsToState(props), [props])
```

And to answer your question,

> What I really want is for the setState in the first useEffect to be done "quietly" and not to trigger the 2nd useEffect.

You can store the relevant info (dependencies of 2nd `useEffect`) in  a seperate state varable, and then use that.

Refs:

1. [You might not need an effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) (React docs)
2. [Summing up some of nuances of useEffect](https://www.shivamjha.io/blog/useEffect-firing-twice)

Comment: sorry i should clarify, 'state' here uses 'useState', so i do have to use 'useEffect' to update the state object when props change

Comment: as to the 2nd point, the 'state' object here is a fairly large object which is being passed back to an API call, any of its fields can change, i'm not seeing how modifying the dependency array will help

Comment: Are you using `preferencesChanged` someplace else? If not, define it inside `useEffect` and then call it. Is your linter not warning you about this ? ([eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks))